# NSIS section hide (compile and execute)

Tags: nsis

Well I found a few forum topics on nsis section hiding, also checked NSIS help but couldn't find my answer. I want a simple thing i.e. per my requirement I want to hide a section completely without commenting whole lines of code.

Now this should effect two things.

1. Section should be removed from compilation scope just like if I commented those lines.
2. Do not execute the section codes from installer.

If I use #, /o or - before section name. It's doing the 2nd point. But any way to achieve the first one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional compiling:

```
!define INCLUDESECTION

!ifdef INCLUDESECTION
Section "section1"
   ...
SectionEnd
!endif
```

You can also decide to include the section or not, from command line:

```
makensis.exe /DINCLUDESECTION example.nsi
```

In this case, you don't have to define INCLUDESECTION inside your nsis code.

Comment: Yes, that's a good one. But there is no built in command switch to skip hidden section compilation. Am I right?

Comment: a hidden section is a section which isn't shown to the user on the Components page. It isn't a "disabled" or inactive section, so a hidden section is executed in runtime, so it has to be compiled.

Comment: Okay. So hidden means only skipping user view. What about 'SectionIn' command? Found some post on: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=255299.

Comment: SectionIn selects which install type a section belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to disable sections at compile time to avoid it's selection/execution because:

1. Sections designed all about of code runtime behaviour, not of compile time. Otherwise it produces an infinite set of !ifdef...!endif for section scope control and bloatware compilation definitions incorporation like yours INCLUDESECTION.
2. At some point you will want to switch a section selection/visibility in the runtime which will force you to mix the runtime and compile time code that is even worse.

I may think it all went from an invalid undestanding of section selection/hideness behaviour in the runtime. So, to ensure you that theres is no much problems to use section selection/hiding in the runtime you have to understand several things to think on:

1. In Windows sections implemented through the SysTreeView32 control and inherites/workarounds all issues introduced by such controls. This means you have to hide/unhide sections (controls items) in a Page Pre (OnCreate) function instead of Page Show (OnShow) function which basically uses to control a section visibility state.
2. Sections can still run even if hidden, because the hidden state is independent to the selection state. To hide section you have to set empty string to the section name when the selection state introduced by the respective contol item flag. So, in some cases you might have to test a section hideness at the section code block to skip it's further execution.
3. Parent section selection triggers children selection recursively by the control. But because hidden not readonly children sections does select too, you have to update parent selection state from the "Partial Selected"/"All Selected"/"All Unselected" manually at the end of your .onSelChange handler function to fixup control checkboxes visibility to it's actual appearence.

So, to do all things right you have to:

1. Write the set of the UpdateSectionGroupSelectionN macroses to postprocess each section group visibility state update, where N - is number of subitems in a section. If all not hidden subitems in a section is selected, then parent must be updated to the "All Selected" state. If some of not hidden subitems in a section is selected, then parent must be updated to the "Partial Selected" state. If all subitems is hidden then you have to decide that to do with such parent items (may be it's should not even change or must be hidden too in the Page Pre function).
2. Add to a section beggining hideness state check code to bypass section further execution in case if other section neighbors could be hidden or in case of some other reason.

I know all said it's a bit tricky to do, but you will find that this way is almost one common way to fixup all section issues at once and for all and avoid the code further complication on the way.